# How to make @escaping closure optional?

Tags: swift, closures

I am having difficulties with making this function pass through optional values, I am using an `@escaping` closure, but the issue arises where my code demands a certain parameter. So in this instance, I am trying to upload two images. However, the third parameter is giving me trouble. How can I make it so that a certain parameter(s) is optional/doesn't need to be called. And I can inject the data into a certain parameter if it does exist?

This is my code -

```
static func uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage(data: Data? = nil, secondData: Data? = nil, thirdData: Data? = nil, onSuccess: @escaping (_ imageURL: String, _ secondImageURL: String?, _ thirdImageURL: String?) -> Void) {
    let firstPhotoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
    let secondPhotoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
    let thirdPhotoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_REF_ROOT ).child("posts").child(firstPhotoIdString)

    storageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let secondStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_REF_ROOT ).child("posts").child(secondPhotoIdString)

        secondStorageRef.putData(secondData!, metadata: nil) { (secondMetadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                secondStorageRef.setValue(nil, forKey: secondPhotoIdString)
                return
            }

            let thirdStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_REF_ROOT ).child("posts").child(thirdPhotoIdString)
            thirdStorageRef.putData(thirdData!, metadata: nil) { (thirdMetadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                if let firstPhotoURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString, let secondPhotoURL = secondMetadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString, let thirdPhotoURL = thirdMetadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                    onSuccess(firstPhotoURL, secondPhotoURL, thirdPhotoURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will do conditional checks to see if there is valid data to pass through but I want this type of outcome:

- If value doesn't exist I do not need to include a certain parameter(s), after the conditional checks have been done

  - If it doesn't exist, forget about that parameter and carry on

I have found that if can make multiple instances of the same code and change the parameters, but I will need 20 instances, and as you can tell, that would not be efficient what so ever. So how can I have all parameters optional and pass data through without the code needing/demand every parameter?

I know a similar question has been asked, but I read it and didn't find it useful.

Thank you.

EDIT - More information

I am trying to upload images to Firebase. I have three parameters (for 3 images), however, I would like the function to be scalable in terms of it doesn't matter how many images I have, I can upload accordingly.

This is my call to the function:

```
static func uploadDataToServer(data: Data, secondData: Data? = nil, thirdData: Data? = nil, firstVideoURL: URL? = nil, secondVideoURL: URL? = nil, thirdVideoURL: URL? = nil, caption: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if let secondImageData = secondData {
            uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage(data: data, secondData: secondImageData) { (firstPhotoURL, secondPhotoURL, nil )  in
                self.sendDataToDatabase(firstPhotoURL: firstPhotoURL, secondPhotoURL: secondPhotoURL, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to upload two images, even thought I have three parameters hence why I set all but the first data AKA first image to nil. My issue is the code either expects a third image or it will crash because there is no third image. I inject the image from the ViewController class by passing the image (from the `ImagePickerController`) and using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.

Comment: I have tried to add `= nil` but get the following error  - `default argument not permitted in a tuple type`

Comment: Adding names to the completionparsameters is pointless `@escaping (_ imageURL: String, _ secondImageURL: String?, _ thirdImageURL: String?)` change it to `@escaping (String, String?,  String?)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I have tried it, yet when calling the code, it still expects 3 parameters.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve your issue. Just to let you know the result would be the same with much less code

Comment: @LeoDabus Ahhh I see what you did. Pointless? Maybe so haha, but in terms of readability, pretty useful. But that's my two cents.

Comment: btw you should just pass the error also as a parameter `(String, String?, String?, Error?)` and in case an error occurs you would pass `onSuccess(nil, nil, nil, error)`. Btw I would name it `completion` instead of `onSuccess` as it may not be successful

Comment: @LeoDabus Adding names to completion parameters is not pointless. If you do so, you can use those names in the QuickHelp documentation. I'd say it's "six of one, a half dozen of another". Do I make method signature cleaner, or do I document it nicely.

Comment: @LeoDabus @Rob Passed `nil` into the parameters, get an error saying `Expected type`.

Comment: @SwiftLearner Correct, you cannot use `= nil` to supply default values to optional parameters of the closure. You can only do that for function declarations, not for closures. With closures, you have to explicitly supply all of the parameters (specifying `nil` where appropriate) when you call that closure.

Comment: @Rob Ah crap. How could I possibly solve this issue without make 20 instances of the same code?

Comment: @SwiftLearner not related your question `error?.localizedDescription`  localizedDescription is redundant. just say `(error ?? "no error")`

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question, adding example of why the absence of default parameter values for closures is so problematic. I'm not following your comment. Frankly, your hard coded `firstPhotoIdString`, `secondPhotoIdString`, etc. with nested calls is worrisome. Are you saying you have 20 of those? Use some collection or other structure, not individual parameters and nested calls like this.

Comment: @Rob regarding the QuickHelp/documentation you are correct.

Comment: @SwiftLearner Thanks for trying to clarify your question, but I'm still not following you. This is still very unclear what the broader problem is.

Comment: @Rob I have updated my code. The issue is I wish to upload two images, but the code expects three. So it will crash. I wish to have it so even if I don't have three, the code will execute and there isn't a problem. But it crashes because `thirdData` (from the function `uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage`) is nil.

Comment: So supply three, passing `nil` for the ones that are applicable. If you code is crashing, show us the exact error you received to show us how it's crashing (e.g. are not just trying to force unwrapping those optionals or something silly like that)?

Comment: @Rob I don't have 20, but yes, users can have upto 20 images. So I would need to create 20 instances of `photoIDStrings` in order to upload and retrieve posts.

Comment: @Rob In my View controller I am passing this into the third parameter - `self.thirdImageData`. I get this by declaring a Data variable - ` var thirdImageData: Data?` and then assigning the chosen image to this variable. `       thirdSelectedImage = image
            thirdImageView.image = image
            self.thirdImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)`

Comment: I'm still not following what you're trying to do, but if I wanted a function that I could use to upload X files, I'd use a single array parameter of photo Ids rather than one parameter per photo id. If you want to handle a variable number of parameters, it's generally best to use some collection structure, not unique parameters for each possible value you might be passing.

Comment: @LeoDabus `NSUUID().uuidString` generates a unique string, which will allow me to retrieve all posts and clear any confusion. Yes, I do use a combination of `if let` or `guard`. Haha.

Comment: @SwiftLearner my bad I mixed uuidString with `device  identifierForVendor uuidString`